# How do I get access to HTTP error body using a OpenAPI Generator Client SDK

Tags: go, openapi-generator

[OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) creates API functions that follow the general pattern:

`func (api *MyAPI) OperationId(context.Context) (ResponseStruct, *http.Response, error)`

How can I retrieve the HTTP body on an error? When the HTTP Status Code is an error, `error` is not `nil`, however, it does not include the body and neither does `*http.Response` as the body has been read already. And, the error is not unmarshaled into the ResponseStruct as the success and failure definitions. are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated client creates a `mypackage.GenericOpenAPIError` struct which is returned as an `error`, where `mypackage` is the package name of the client. It stores the HTTP error body in the `GenericOpenAPIError.body` property which can be accessed by the `Body() []byte` function. However, because function definition returns an `error` which does not support the `Body()` function the error needs to be cast before you can access it.

Here's the code that creates the error from a generated client:

```
if localVarHttpResponse.StatusCode >= 300 {
    newErr := GenericOpenAPIError{
        body:  localVarBody,
        error: localVarHttpResponse.Status,
    }
```

To access the body property, casting the error is needed. For example:

```
data, resp, err := myclient.MyAPI.OperationId(context.Background())
if err != nil && resp.StatusCode >= 300 {
    openAPIErr := err.(mypackage.GenericOpenAPIError)
    fmt.Println(string(openAPIErr.Body()))
}
```

Since this needs to be decoded into a struct in the generated client package, it would be useful to add this as a helper function in the client package.